# How to set callback_url to facebook subscription to get facebook realtime updates using java graph api?

Tags: facebook-java-api

I have used the below link to set the subscription for facebook application:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/MY_APP_ID/subscriptions?callback_url=MY_CALLBACK_URL?object=user&fields=feed&verify_token=MY_VERIFICATION_CODE&access_token=My_App_ID|MY_APP_SECRET

For this I am getting empty json object:
{
   "data": [``
   ]
}

Please any one help me to set the subscription for my facebook application and to get the realtime updates from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending a HTTP GET request instead of a HTTP POST request.

The HTTP GET request will return the subscriptions that app has, which seems to be none.
You need to first create a subscription to your callback_url by using a POST request instead.

Comment: I am sending post request to the facebook and facebook server is calling my callback_url through GET request. It is always returning the "{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#2201) response does not match challenge, expected value = '2074165530', received='Mode: subscribe & ch...'",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2201
  }
}" as a response please suggest us to get the realtime updates from the facebook.

Comment: @Ram challenge you are sending via `verify_token` isn't being matched in your callback url code.